# How to sync Google Drive/One Drive from Linux command line without Graphical interface

Tags: linux, postgresql, command-line-interface, database-backups, drive

I would like to perform my database backup inside google drive. That's why I was trying to sync google drive on my VM(ubuntu) using the command-line interface. The way I have found so far is the rclone. But at a certain step, it's waiting for the browser response that's where I stuck to as I don't have any graphical interface to respond.

Is there any way to do that without any sort of graphical interaction?

Comment: When registering a client to something like Google drive you frequently need to confirm your identity via a web-browser. You don't need to do that from the same machine though. Typically there would be a URL printed that you could copy.

Comment: @RichardHuxton yeap, there is a URL. How can I proceed with that? Would you mind explaining a bit more precisely?

Comment: It prints the url - you copy and paste that into a local browser - it displays a web-page and you read the instructions on that web-page.

Comment: ow, this idea clicked with me as well initially. But I think there was an issue. Whatever, let me give it a try once again...